# Sql list unregistered classroom

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

There is one student. This student is enrolling in classes. What I want is to list the classes where this student is not registered.

My SQL query is like this.

```
SELECT * FROM class, userClass WHERE class.id <> userClass.class AND userClass.user<>$userid
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Use WHERE NOT EXISTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to assume your table structure and I hope I got it right. The classic approach would be with LEFT JOIN and IS NULL:

```
select
    c.*
from
    class c left join userClass uC on c.id = uC.class and uC.user = $userid
where
    uC.class is null
```

or using NOT IN

```
select
    *
from
    class
where
    id not in (select class from userClass where user = $userid)
```

BTW: You should read a bit about database naming conventions - like using plural names for tables (`classes`, `userClasses`) and properly identifying keys - if table `classes` has an `id` then you should refer to it in related tables by `classId`, etc.